# How can I update a TextFlow.paragraph.span object and get it to reflect on the view?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I have created a Flex TextArea.  In ActionScript created a ParagraphElement and then Span element thusly:

```
<s:TextArea id="te"/>

...

pe = new ParagraphElement();
se = new SpanElement();

se.text = "banana";
pe.addChild(se);
te.addChild(pe);
```

Everything seems to work out fine.  I see a banana on the stage.  Later I attempt to update the value of se (it is a class variable) and the change is not reflected on the stage.

```
se.text = "apple";
```

OR

```
se.replaceText(0, se.text.length, "apple");
```

I really need to be able to update the SpanElement!

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.  Hopefully this will help others find it faster.

In my app I was actually creating multiple SpanElements and adding them to a single paragraph.  When attempting to change one of those elements the value would change but would not reflect.  The ParagraphElement was combining all of those SpanElements into a single (new) element so my reference to the SpanElement I had created wasn't actually being used any more.

My solution was to create a new ParagraphElement for every SpanElement that I wanted to show.  It makes twice as many objects but acts the way I expect.